# grails spring-security-core/ui creates locked user accounts by default

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am building a simple grails app that does not have access to email. However `spring-security-core` creates users whose `ACCOUNT_LOCKED` property is set to `TRUE` by default. This means that such users can never login because they cannot unlock their accounts.

Is there a simple fix for this behaviour?

Here is my `User` class:

```
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString
import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic

@GrailsCompileStatic
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes='username')
@ToString(includes='username', includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        (UserRole.findAllByUser(this) as List<UserRole>)*.role as Set<Role>
    }

    static constraints = {
        password nullable: false, blank: false, password: true
        username nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }
}
```

I have tried initializing `accountLocked` to `false` but to no avail.

Comment: "However spring-security-core creates users whose ACCOUNT_LOCKED property is set to TRUE by default." - The plugin doesn't create users on its own.  Can you show whatever code you are using that creates accounts?

Comment: I haven't written any code that creates users. If the spring-security-core plugin isn't creating users, perhaps the spring-security-ui plugin is?

Comment: What are the usernames of the automatically created users?

Comment: The users aren't created automatically. They are created when someone registers a new user at `http://localhost:8080/register/register`. The username I tried was just `peter`

Comment: Are you using the default behavior provided by `spring-security-ui`?

Comment: Yes I am. The simplest thing that could possibly work.